# Responsive timeline UI with Bootstrap3

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, timeline

How can I create a UI with a vertical timeline bar where on desktop it shows as timeline-bar in middle and event boxes on both sides. On smaller mobile screen, the timeline-bar on the left and all event boxes on the right.

Using JQuery in combination with responsive classes is okay, just need to show all event boxes, so hiding alternate boxes with xs-hidden won't do.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/n82ek/2/

Reduce expand size of result window to see responsive behavior.

What needs to happen? Move the bar left for xs display
Nice to have: Also add the timelineDot on line alongside the box.

Please Refer to a sample timeline ui pattern image attached.... and Thank you!

[image]

**Current HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="timelineBar"></div>
    <div class="timelineDot"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="shadowBox">right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="shadowBox">left</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="shadowBox">right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="shadowBox">left</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Current CSS:**

```
@import url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.timelineBar {
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.shadowBox {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.796875) 0px 0px 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.796875) 0px 0px 2px;
    border:2px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.timelineDot{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 15px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code or put it in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Which control is the one in the image you attached. That's exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

### "Timeline (responsive)" snippet:

This looks very, very close to what your example shows. The bootstrap snippet linked below covers all the bases you are looking for. I've been considering it myself, with the same requirements you have ( especially responsiveness ). This morphs well between screen sizes and devices.

You can fork this and use it as a great starting point for your specific expectations:

- http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/timeline-responsive

---

Here are two screenshots I took for you... wide and thin:

[image: wide]
[image: thin]

Comment: Yep. This looks good. I implemented mine with css+JavaScript - a resize event handler. This looks like a pure css solution. Will definitely try and customize it for my requirement. Thanks!

Comment: Really glad to help //

Comment: The link seems to be down :(

Comment: brilliant, great resource, simple and effective.

Answer (score 20):

### [BootFlat](http://bootflat.github.io)

You can also try [BootFlat](http://bootflat.github.io), which has a section in [their documentation](http://bootflat.github.io/documentation.html) specifically for crafting Timelines:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```css
.timeline {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline:before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1.5px;
}

.timeline > li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline > li:before,
.timeline > li:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.timeline > li:after {
  clear: both;
}

.timeline > li:before,
.timeline > li:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.timeline > li:after {
  clear: both;
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
  width: 46%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  right: -15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 0 solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  right: -14px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 14px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid #fff;
  border-right: 0 solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
  color: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background-color: #999999;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
}

.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
  float: right;
}

.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:before {
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: auto;
}

.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:after {
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 14px;
  left: -14px;
  right: auto;
}

.timeline-badge.primary {
  background-color: #2e6da4 !important;
}

.timeline-badge.success {
  background-color: #3f903f !important;
}

.timeline-badge.warning {
  background-color: #f0ad4e !important;
}

.timeline-badge.danger {
  background-color: #d9534f !important;
}

.timeline-badge.info {
  background-color: #5bc0de !important;
}

.timeline-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: inherit;
}

.timeline-body > p,
.timeline-body > ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.timeline-body > p + p {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1 id="timeline">Timeline</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="timeline">
    <li>
      <div class="timeline-badge"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i></div>
      <div class="timeline-panel">
         <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 11 hours ago via Twitter</small></p>
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
          <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 11 hours ago via Twitter</small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
          <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo.
            Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="timeline-inverted">
      <div class="timeline-badge warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></div>
      <div class="timeline-panel">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
          <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo.
            Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
          <p>Suco de cevadiss, é um leite divinis, qui tem lupuliz, matis, aguis e fermentis. Interagi no mé, cursus quis, vehicula ac nisi. Aenean vel dui dui. Nullam leo erat, aliquet quis tempus a, posuere ut mi. Ut scelerisque neque et turpis posuere
            pulvinar pellentesque nibh ullamcorper. Pharetra in mattis molestie, volutpat elementum justo. Aenean ut ante turpis. Pellentesque laoreet mé vel lectus scelerisque interdum cursus velit auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
            elit. Etiam ac mauris lectus, non scelerisque augue. Aenean justo massa.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="timeline-badge danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></div>
      <div class="timeline-panel">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
          <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo.
            Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="timeline-inverted">
      <div class="timeline-panel">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
          <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo.
            Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="timeline-badge info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i></div>
      <div class="timeline-panel">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
          <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo.
            Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
          <hr>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="timeline-panel">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
          <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo.
            Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="timeline-inverted">
      <div class="timeline-badge success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i></div>
      <div class="timeline-panel">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
          <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo.
            Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/bsngr/pen/Ifvbi/

Comment: please provide some explanation

Comment: I want something like this but without using jquery http://codepen.io/codyhouse/pen/FdkEf

Comment: Please then edit your above post and elaborate what you did as a part of answer to this question. If you have question instead then please post a new question with reference of  codepen.io/codyhouse/pen/FdkEf